# Pass argument to jasmine unit test from karma?

Tags: jasmine, gulp, karma-runner

I have some unit tests that where I'm using server paths to hit my mock stubs. Currently I'm add the URL into each test. I'd really like to pass this URL from my gulp task into the unit tests. Is this possible?

```
  require('.path_to_my_karma').apply(null, [].concat(args).concat([**host_url**]));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `karma` you can pass in custom options;

```
karma start --my-custom-url http://google.com
```

Then in your `karma.conf.js` you can access them like so;

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  console.log('URL passed in from command line is %s', config.myCustomUrl);
  config.set({
    // ...
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure from your comment @Jimi whether you want to pass data from gulp to karma, or from karma to your jasmine tests. This answer explains how to pass data into karma from the command line, which you could run from gulp.